# How can I create a download link for IPFS-hosted files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipfs

I have been playing around with [IPFS](http://ipfs.io) a lot recently, and have been wondering how to make a download link for files that gives them a custom name. The standard `<a>` tag download attribute doesn't work:

```
<a href="http://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmV9tSDx9UiPeWExXEeH6aoDvmihvx6jD5eLb4jbTaKGps" download="ipfs-p2p-file-system.pdf">foo</a>
```

Is there a way I can work around this by using JavaScript or Jquery? At a last resort I could route the files through the server, but I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your file by wrapping it inside a folder and therefore preserving the name of the original file. Try:

```
$ ipfs add -w example.txt
added QmbFMke1KXqnYyBBWxB74N4c5SBnJMVAiMNRcGu6x1AwQH example.txt
added QmVFDXxAEC5iQ9ptb36dxzpNsQjVatvxhG44wK7PpRzsDE
```

This way, you can point to the last hash, which is a MerkleDAG Node that points to your file, preserving the name of it. Let me know if this solution works for you :)

Comment: This works very well for a static set of files, but by adding files into the folder, the hash changes each time, i.e:

Comment: @Will thats the hole point of the hash, but you can publish it `ipfs name publish QmVFDXxAEC5iQ9ptb36dxzpNsQjVatvxhG44wK7PpRzsDE`  and then use this link : /ipns/<peerid>

Comment: Did this answered your question Will? Let me know if you still need help.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding "?filename=filename.pdf&download=true" at the end of CID.

Like so:

```
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmV9tSDx9UiPeWExXEeH6aoDvmihvx6jD5eLb4jbTaKGps?filename=filename.pdf&download=true
```